# HTML5 Pushstate SEO

Tags: web-applications, seo, pushstate

Google uses the *?_escaped_fragment_* when it finds a hashbang (#) in a requested URL, but in my new application I am using HTML5 PushState, so I don't use hashbangs anymore, how does google know how to route to */?_escaped_fragment_=blogs* instead of */blogs* if it does not contain a hashbang (#).

Does it rely on robot.txt or sitemap.xml?

I understand that Google routes to a different url, and then returning a HTML snapshot. Are there any libraries (prefer Node.js or PHP) for generating one? Tutorials perhaps?

Been in the Google Developer documents all day but just could not figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #! support from Google is a kind of hack to solve a problem while the pushstate feature is a clean solution. They are different and your fragment parameter has no meaning with pushstate.

You need to make sure all the real URLs that you create via pushstate return the correct and relevant content. The Google will then index it like a normal website.